# hook_block visibility

Tags: 6, blocks

I have a custom module defining a block which needs some complex page visibility rules that I'll write later. In building out the basic `hook_block` code the `visibility` and `pages` settings don't seem to be working when returning `FALSE`.

```
function popup_footer_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks[0] = array(
      'info' => t('Popup Footer'),
      'visibility' => 2,
      'pages' => popup_footer_block_visibility(),
    );

    return $blocks;
  }
  else if ($op == 'view') {
    switch ($delta) {
      case 0:
        $block = array('content' => 'foo bar');
        break;
    }

    return $block;
  }
}

function popup_footer_block_visibility() {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'pages' => '<?php return popup_footer_block_visibility(); ?>'` worked. Disable the module, delete the module entry from the database, re-enable the module.

Answer (score 0):

When the block visibility is set to 2, `$block[0]['pages']` needs to be a string that can be passed to [`drupal_eval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_eval/6.x) as first argument. In fact, the code which handles the block visibility is the following one.

```
  // Match path if necessary
  if ($block->pages) {
    if ($block->visibility < 2) {
      $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
      // Compare with the internal and path alias (if any).
      $page_match = drupal_match_path($path, $block->pages);
      if ($path != $_GET['q']) {
        $page_match = $page_match || drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $block->pages);
      }
      // When $block->visibility has a value of 0, the block is displayed on
      // all pages except those listed in $block->pages. When set to 1, it
      // is displayed only on those pages listed in $block->pages.
      $page_match = !($block->visibility xor $page_match);
    }
    else {
      $page_match = drupal_eval($block->pages);
    }
  }
```

Comment: So it needs a PHP string to interpret that returns boolean value? If I change that function to `return 'return false';` it still doesn't work. Thx

Comment: `return '<?php return false; ?>';` rather

Comment: I don't recall if the PHP code requires `<?php ?>`; the user interface for creating a block says that. It should be one of the following: `'pages' => 'if ($condition) {return FALSE;}'` or `'pages' => '<?php if ($condition) {return FALSE;} ?>'`. Write the condition you need to make the block not visible instead of `$condition`. For sure it needs to contain the code to be executed, as string, which is what `drupal_eval()` expects as its parameter.